# Chrome extension detect Google search refresh

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

How can my content script detect a refresh of Google's search?
I believe it is an AJAX reload of the page and not a "real" refresh, so my events won't detect the refresh.

Is it possible to detect it somehow in both a Google Chrome extension and a Firefox WebExtensions add-on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google search is a dynamically updated page. Several well-known methods exist to detect an update: [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), timer-based approach (see [waitForKeyElements](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891) wrapper), and an event used by the site like pjax:end on GitHub.

Luckily, Google Search in Chrome browser uses `message` event, so here's our content script:

```js
window.addEventListener('message', function onMessage(e) {
    // console.log(e);
    if (typeof e.data === 'object' && e.data.type === 'sr') {
        onSearchUpdated();
    }
});

function onSearchUpdated() {
    document.getElementById('resultStats').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}
```

This method relies on an undocumented site feature which doesn't work in Firefox, for example.

A more reliable crossbrowser method available to Chrome extensions and WebExtensions is to monitor page url changes because Google Search results page always updates its URL hash part. We'll need a [background/event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages), [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) listener, and [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging):

- background.js

  ```js
  var rxGoogleSearch = /^https?:\/\/(www\.)?google\.(com|\w\w(\.\w\w)?)\/.*?[?#&]q=/;
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
      if (rxGoogleSearch.test(changeInfo.url)) {
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, 'url-update');
      }
  });
  ```
- content.js

  ```js
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (msg === 'url-update') {
          onSearchUpdated();
      }
  });

  function onSearchUpdated() {
      document.getElementById('resultStats').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }
  ```
- manifest.json: [background/event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) and [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) declarations, `"tabs"` [permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions).

Comment: is there also anything for firefox? when implementing this event, the  function is never triggered. i think the message object doesnt hold the specified keys in the if statement. but how is this possible? Sorry for OT